# Polybase metadata query

Tags: sql-server, polybase

All,

Polybase keeps running this query, or variation of, every 1 minute +/-.  This shows on the source system it's getting it's data from.  While usually very fast, if any clustered index is rebuilt during maintenance is blocks this query.

This doesn't appear to be part of the external table call as I've stopped the job running that and we are still seeing this.  Interestingly, it appears to only be called on tables with partitioning enabled (or at least I haven't captured the query on tables that aren't partitioned).

Question:

- Anyone have thoughts on what polybase is doing here?
- Why it needs to run this query every 1 minute or so?
- Is there a way to prevent/slowdown the calls during stuff like index maintenance?
- Issues with killing the process on the source system?

Appreciate the help and input.

````
SELECT PARTITION_FUNCTIONS.name
    ,QUOTENAME(COLUMNS.name)
    ,cast(PARTITIONS.partition_number AS NVARCHAR(10))
FROM "<DBName>".sys.indexes AS INDEXES
    ,"<DBName>".sys.partitions AS PARTITIONS
    ,"<DBName>".sys.index_columns AS INDEX_COLUMNS
    ,"<DBName>".sys.columns AS COLUMNS
    ,"<DBName>".sys.partition_functions AS PARTITION_FUNCTIONS
    ,"<DBName>".sys.partition_schemes AS PARTITION_SCHEMES
WHERE INDEXES.object_id = object_id(@0)
    AND INDEXES.type IN (@1,@2,@3)
    AND INDEX_COLUMNS.partition_ordinal = @4
    AND INDEXES.object_id = PARTITIONS.object_id
    AND INDEXES.index_id = PARTITIONS.index_id
    AND INDEXES.object_id = INDEX_COLUMNS.object_id
    AND INDEXES.index_id = INDEX_COLUMNS.index_id
    AND INDEXES.data_space_id = PARTITION_SCHEMES.data_space_id
    AND PARTITION_SCHEMES.function_id = PARTITION_FUNCTIONS.function_id
    AND INDEXES.object_id = COLUMNS.object_id
    AND INDEX_COLUMNS.column_id = COLUMNS.column_id```
````

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to query the external table metadata to identify the fields, data types and lengths, but there are only two times when Polybase does this, at the external table creation, and when querying the data. If you're seeing it every minute with variations, check:

- If you're dropping and creating the external table in a cycle.
- If you're querying the external table in a cycle.
- If it is part of a scale-out group, and if other nodes are querying the external table.
  If you can't identify where it is being triggered, you should drop your external table while not in use to avoid issues with the index maintenance, better than creating a process to kill these sessions indefinitely.
  You can find additional information about how Polybase works in my book "Hands-on data virtualization with Polybase".

Comment: We are querying the external table every 15 minutes or so.  However, this doesn't co-inside with the metadata check.  Additionally, the query runs successfully and as expected, even if the metadata query is blocked.

Not dropping or recreating
Not part of a scaleout group.  

Got a link to that book?

Comment: Yes the query runs successfully no matter if the metadata query is blocked. But it is abnormal that it runs every minute, is it patched to the latest SP? Here is the link to the book: https://www.amazon.com/Hands-Data-Virtualization-Polybase-Accessibility/dp/9390684412

Comment: Close.  Using SQL 2019 Enterprise CU14.  Just missing he most recent Jan CU.  Not seeing anything in there that would point to a fix for this.  Only reference to PB in that CU is for fixing Hadoop queries.

Comment: Try to see if you find something useful, pointing to what is the system doing every minute, in the following locations:
• [sys].[dm_exec_compute_node_errors]: errors
• [sys].[dm_exec_dms_workers], [sys].[dm_exec_distributed_request_steps], [sys].[dm_exec_distributed_sql_requests]: every step executed locally and remotely
• <InstanceRoot>\MSSQL\Log\Polybase\*.log, see how to interpret them with this guide https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/monitor-for-errors-in-your-ssas-ssrs-ssis-agent-and-full-text-services